# PostgreSQL root.crt not loading

Tags: postgresql

I am running postgresql 9.1 on ubuntu 12.04.

I wanted to change the data directory of postgres. So I created a new directory and run initdb. I also made symbolic links of the certificate to the data directory.

But still postgres cant find root.crt:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                   * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2012-08-17 16:02:33 CEST FATAL:  could not load root certificate file "root.crt": no SSL error reported
```

What am I doing wrong?
The data directoy looks like this:

```
ls -la
total 92
drwx------ 13 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:36 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root      4096 Aug 16 13:57 ..
drwx------  5 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:00 base
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:36 global
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:00 pg_clog
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  4476 Aug 16 14:00 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  1636 Aug 16 14:00 pg_ident.conf
drwx------  4 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:00 pg_multixact
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:35 pg_notify
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:00 pg_serial
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:36 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:00 pg_subtrans
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:00 pg_tblspc
drwx------  2 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:00 pg_twophase
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres     4 Aug 16 14:00 PG_VERSION
drwx------  3 postgres postgres  4096 Aug 16 14:00 pg_xlog
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 19169 Aug 16 14:00 postgresql.conf
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres   126 Aug 16 14:35 postmaster.opts
lrwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres    31 Aug 16 14:13 root.crt -> /etc/postgresql-common/root.crt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres    36 Aug 16 14:13 server.crt -> /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
lrwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres    38 Aug 16 14:13 server.key -> /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

so root.crt should be there and visible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you try, $ sudo -u postgres cat /etc/postgresql-common/root.crt and check if the contents of root.crt is displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Chida for your hint!

The output was:

```
 sudo -u postgres cat /etc/postgresql-common/root.crt

This is a dummy root certificate file for PostgreSQL. To enable client side
authentication, add some certificates to it. Client certificates must be signed
with any certificate in this file to be accepted. 

A reasonable choice is to just symlink this file to
/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem; in this case, client certificates need to
be signed by the postgresql server certificate, which might be desirable in
many cases. See

  file:///usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-8.3/html/ssl-tcp.html

for details (in package postgresql-doc-8.3).
```

So I pointed root.crt in the data directory to  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem:

```
 ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem root.crt
```

And then postgresql started without any error!

Answer (score -2):

I ran into this issue, toyed with the symlink and actual /etc/ssl/* directory/file permissions and still kept getting this error.

Eventually, I fixed it by removing the symlinks in /var/lib/postgresql/*/main and copying the .pem and .key file out of the respective directories in /etc/ssl, changed their names to whatever the related symlink name was, set the group owner to ssl-cert, and was able to get the database to finally start back up.